# OFBiz Session gets expired : After FO PDF Download

Tags: session, apache-fop, ofbiz

When we are downloading PDF and accessing, the cross-module session gets expired and rendering the login page again. For example, I am downloading Order FO PDF file and accessing accounting or catalog module session getting expired. This does not happen every time but for the first time when the server is started or restarted.....

Please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: Please specify the exact version you are using and are there any custom changes?

Comment: I am using OFBiz 16.11.01 version same issue I can replicate in OFBiz [demo site](https://demo-trunk.ofbiz.apache.org/accounting/control/main). No customization in the code.

Answer (score -1):

Able to replicate the issue on demo site. We'll check it soon. Hint for trying at your end to check to fix the issue, if user click on other link in the same module after downloading the PDF and go to cross-module links then session persist. Trace both request should take you to some solution.

Found jira ticket with same details, will work on it asap- https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/OFBIZ-10556